# R - how to create sequence

Tags: r, sequence

How can I create this sequence in R?

I've been watching some guides but these are simple sequences.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

It is vectorized.  We can do

```
 2^(1:10)/(1:10)
```

Comment: thanks you so much :3